# Capistrano 3: how to get release_name

Tags: capistrano

In Capistrano 2.x the DSL used to provide a variable/method `release_name` that would return the name of the directory into which the app was just deployed, e.g. `20140225134251`, corresponding to `.../releases/20140225134251`.

I can't seem to find an equivalent for this in cap 3.

Also missing is `current_revision`, although I've replicated that with

```
`git rev-parse HEAD`.chomp
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try release_path and release_timestamp?

Comment: release_timestamp is what I was looking for, thanks.